# How to change referrer in Google Tag Manager via Javascript Variable?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, http-referer

After reading this [article](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/referral-exclusion-on-receipt-page/), it seems like I can create a custom Javascript variable to reset the referrer in GA tracking. I've created the variable 'referer' with the following code:

```
function() {
    return {{Page Path}}.indexOf('/path/on/site') > -1 ? null : 
              document.referrer;
}
```

and added it to the Page View Event, and published those changes. However, when I go to `/path/on/site` still see the regular `document.referrer` passed in the Chrome GA Debugger. I do see a GTM Built in Variable called 'Referrer' - would that be overriding my custom 'referrer' variable? ... or, would I still see the original referrer in the GA Debugger, but then it wouldn't get counted in the Analytics on the GA side...?

Comment: If the GA debugger shows the DR parameter (Reference ) it will be on the data. Check if your URL is matching with the indexOf condition. Because the Function is properly created

Comment: I've removed the built in 'HTTP Referrer' GTM variable and added my own as a custom variable with the above code, but am still seeing the 'Referring URL' as the document.referrer in the debugger and not null.